# Bootsfaces modalbox filled with data from a dataTable column

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I am working with JSF 2.0 and Bootsfaces 0.9.1. I have a dataTable based on user data from the database. Each column also contains of a couple of buttons to modify the data.

[image]

When I click on the pencil (edit user), a modalbox is displayed, in which I want to modify the respective data.

[image]

Since I want to edit the data, I want the current information filled into the text boxes automatically. How can I do that?

Here's the xhtml source:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <b:dataTable value="#{membersController.users}"
                 var="user"
                 id="users-table"
                 page-length="25"
                 row-highlight="true">
        <b:dataTableColumn label="Id" value="#{user.userId}"/>
        <b:dataTableColumn label="User name" value="#{user.userName}"/>
        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Operations"/>
            </f:facet>
            <b:button style="padding: 0 4px;" iconAwesome="pencil" look="link" p:data-target="#userEditModal" p:data-toggle="modal"
                      onclick="return false;"/>
            <b:button style="padding: 0 4px;" iconAwesome="trash" look="link" p:data-target="#userEditModal" p:data-toggle="modal"
                      onclick="return false;"/>
        </h:column>
    </b:dataTable>
    <b:modal id="userEditModal" title="Modal Example" styleClass="modalPseudoClass">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputText value="User name:"/>
            <b:inputText>
            </b:inputText>
        </h:panelGrid>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <b:button value="close" dismiss="modal" onclick="return false;"/>
            <b:button value="Ok" look="primary" dismiss="modal" onclick="return false;"/>
        </f:facet>
    </b:modal>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bug in BootsFaces 0.9.1 and below. I've solved it in BootsFaces-0.9.2-SNAPSHOT. Note that this is not a production-ready version, but a developer snapshot. See [this entry on how to get the snapshot](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/369).

I've documented how to use buttons in a data table [in our developer showcase](http://www3.bootsfaces.net/Showcase/forms/DataTable.jsf). Scroll down to the latest example. The example uses a kind of in-cell-editing instead of the modal dialog, but I'm sure you'll be able to adapt the example. If not, don't hesitate to ask.

The original bug was reported [here](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/486). If you feel our bugfix is still incomplete, feel free to report the bug on our bug tracker. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for your response. My implementation of the button now looks like this: `<b:commandButton style="padding: 0 4px;" iconAwesome="pencil" look="link" ajax="true" update="userEditModal" onclick="ajax:membersController.setSelectedUser(user)" oncomplete="$('#userEditModal').modal();return false;"/>`

Comment: But unfortunately, I get an InstantiationException when I use inputFields. Probably only a development state.

Comment: Okay, never mind. It's working again. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great news. I read about your `InstantiationException` and tried to understand it, but I didn't manage to do so. Maybe it was really a development state problem? I've learned it's always a bad idea to ignore errors that appear and vanish for no apparent reason. If it occurs again, don't hesitate to tell us!